# Object/subject question

Tags: subjects, objects

Given the sentence:

> I gave Tom a cup.

I can say, that

```
I is the subject.
```

But what is object here:

```
"Tom" or "a cup"
```

?

Comment: An indirect object is the recipient of the direct object

Comment: Denis, look up this article: "[Ditransitive Verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)"

Comment: @CopperKettle I believe your answer is the best, could you convert it, please.

Comment: "I is" is too regular for such idiomatic language as English. The English irregularity is "I always am". Or, you is just a more advanced learner than I am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denis, look up this article: "[Ditransitive Verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb)". A ditransitive verb can have two objects, one direct, one indirect. They are also called *primary* and *secondary*.

In the sentence

> I gave **Tom** a **cup**.

**Cup** is the direct object, and **Tom**, the indirect.

Comment: `ngram` shows that the term *ditransitive* is a relatively new word. It was born in the LSD-era.

Comment: Thanks, @TRomano! That explains why I've been getting such a kick out of using this term. I hope it's not a Schedule I word. ^_^

Comment: And you will probably use it again some time in the future.

Comment: Nah, I can go cold turkey on *ditransitive* any moment.

Comment: M-m-m-m-m. Cold turkey. Cranberry sauce. BRB.

Answer (score 4):

Who finally receives? TOM, so it's object. Okay, What you give? A cup, so cup too is an object.

So, the question is which is direct and which is indirect.

> I gave Tom a cup - TOM is the indirect object of the verb *give*

Excerpt from [the page having useful information](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-direct-indirect-object.php#.VHheb8lvB8E)

> An indirect object is the recipient of the direct object, or an otherwise affected participant in the event. There must be a direct object for an indirect object to be placed in a sentence. In other words an indirect object cannot exist without a direct object.

Answer (score 3):

"Tom" and "a cup" are both objects. "Tom" is an indirect object whereas "a cup" is a direct object.