# Sentence structure of "[Something] helped win her the respect [of somebody]"?

Tags: syntax, objects, infinitive-clauses, indirect-objects

I encountered this sentence:

> 1. Her unquestioned probity helped *win her* the respect of her fellow
>      judges.

I take it to mean

> 2. Her unquestioned probity helped *her win* the respect of her fellow
>      judges.

How can we describe the sentence structure of #1?

Answer (score 1):

> Her unquestioned probity helped win her the respect of her fellow judges.

*Her* here acts as the Indirect Object: the beneficiary of the *winning* achieved (presumably) by this jurist's many excellent personal qualities.

This is not an uncommon or literary use, although it is more usual to express the beneficiary with a preposition phrase:

> Olmos' field goal with just 30 seconds remaining won the game **for the Tigers**.
>   Her unquestioned probity helped win the respect of her fellow judges **for Judge Harwell**.

But note that in this particular case putting the *for* phrase at the end creates an ambiguity: was respect won *for her* or was it *respect for her* that was won? And with the pronoun, *for her*, the phrase is really too 'light' (has too many words) to follow the much heavier direct object *the respect of her fellow judges*. Bare *her* in the ordinary Indirect Object location is really the best choice here.

Comment: +1 A very basic sentence with an indirect object is explained [here,](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40652/object-subject-question/40656#40656) where "Her unquestioned probity" = "I"; "helped win" = "gave"; "her" = "Tom"; "the respect of her fellow judges" = "a cup". If StoneyB's excellent in-depth description is a bit complicated for you, it may be useful to first understand that simpler explanation.

Comment: Nice post, but the OP's problem is that they aren't sure what the *subject* of the verb *win* should be.

Comment: I understood the meaning of the sentence, "Her unquestioned probity helped win the respect of her fellow judges", but I really don't undesrtand if it is the same meaning of with or without "her" after "helped win".